# If a deck of cards is divided into 4 hands, what is the probability that the north and east hands have the same number of spades

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, card-games

Suppose we deal four 13-card bridge hands from an ordinary 52-card deck. What is the probability that the North and East hands each have exactly the same number of spades?

The solution I got was

$$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^6\binom{39}{13-i,13-i}}{\binom{52}{13,13}}$$

The textbook only answers odd numbered questions, is my solution correct?

Goal: 
We need to look at how many ways you could have 0 spades in both, 1 spade in both etc. and we need to add up all these combinations, then divide by the total number of ways you could arrange the 52 cards into the 2 hands.

Explanation of equation:

1. For 0 spades in both hands, we need to see how many combinations of cards we can have between both hands but the combinations cannot have any spades. So we subtract 13 spades from the 52 to get 39, then we see how many combinations we can get between the 2 hands.
2. If we have 1 spade in both hands, we have 12 slots left to fill in either hand. So we see how many combinations we can fit into these 2 hands with 12 slots, such that no spades are in them (39 non-spade cards).
3. As we increase the number of spades in both hands, the number of empty slots for the combinations decreases. This decrease goes on till we have a maximum of 6 spades in each hand and we can only have combinations between a remaining 7 cards in each hand.

Comment: How did you arrive at that solution? I have
 $$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^6\binom{13}{i}\binom{39}{13-i}\binom{13-i}{i}\binom{26+i}{13-i}}{\binom{52}{13,13}}$$ as the solution. Note that the cards in the other two hands are not considered.

Comment: @DanielMathias I changed my solution, because I realized I was wayyy off. My new solution is still different from yours. Could you explain where I made a mistake, or why your solution works?

Comment: Your latest attempt is a lot closer. You still need to account for the distribution of spades: $$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^6\binom{13}{i,i}\binom{39}{13-i,13-i}}{\binom{52}{13,13}}$$ is equivalent to what I first posted, the explanation for which I have provided as an answer.

Comment: I have realized that I was not properly using the multinomial. In my first comment, it should be $\binom{52}{13,13,26}$ or more clearly, as in my edited answer, $\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}$

Comment: And the equivalent is $$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^6\binom{13}{i,i,13-2i}\binom{39}{13-i,13-i,13+2i}}{\binom{52}{13,13,26}}$$

Comment: Who cares about the non-spades?  Just count how many ways there are to *place* the 13 spades among the 52 positions *in the deck*, and of these arrangements how many will yield North and East receiving equal counts for spades.  (For simplicity: deal the top 13 cards to North, the next 13 cards to East, and the remaining 26 cards to South and West.)

Comment: @DanielMathias wtf, I made the exact same mistake as you in the notation. For some reason I assumed that I didn't have to show the size of every partition within the notation alike the notation for the binomial coefficient lol i.e. (n-k1-k2...). Nonetheless, I completely understand your solution now, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternatively:** You want to measure the probability for shuffling 13 spades *among the deck* of 52 such that, when dealt, two particular hands have equal spade counts and the rest are distributed among the remaining two hands.

Now there are at total of $\binom{52}{13}$ ways to shuffle *placement* for spades among the deck.  The deck is then dealt so that 13 places belong to North, 13 to East, and 26 to the rest.

Count the ways to attain the desired outcome.  Divide and calculate.

> $$\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^6{{\binom{13}{k}^2\binom{26}{13-2k}}}}{\dbinom{52}{13}}$$

Comment: Either your latex is messed up, or you neglected to show the numerator. Your method could work I guess, but your idea is easily conceived. The difficulty comes in when you actually have to determine what the numerator is. Nonetheless I figured out the solution using Daniel's method above yours. It would be interesting to see your solution to the problem -that is- if you could figure out the numerator...

Comment: You cannot count ways to select $k$ from $13$ places, $k$ from the next $13$ places, and $13-2k$ from the remaining $26$ places, and sum this over $0\leq k\leq 6$ ?

Comment: Yea that solution works, and its a lot easier to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^6\binom{13}{i}\binom{39}{13-i} \binom{13-i}{i}\binom{26+i}{13-i}}{\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}}$$

For each possible number of spades: $\sum_{i=0}^6$

Choose the spades in North's hand: $\binom{13}{i}$

Choose the non-spades in North's hand: $\binom{39}{13-i}$

Choose the spades in East's hand from the remaining spades: $\binom{13-i}{i}$

Choose the non-spades in East's hand from the remaining non-spades: $\binom{26+i}{13-i}$

Take the sum of the products: $\sum_{i=0}^6\binom{13}{i}\binom{39}{13-i} \binom{13-i}{i}\binom{26+i}{13-i}$

Divide by the number of unrestricted hands: $\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}$